# Hiding Zendesk chat button opens chat window. Any fix?

Tags: javascript, zendesk

I have a url I would like to hide the Zendesk chat button on. Looking at their [documentation](https://api.zopim.com/files/meshim/widget/controllers/liveChatAPI/Button-js.html#%24zopim.livechat.button.hide) I see that I need to use the `hideAll()` function. To that end, I have created:

```
$zopim(function () {
   if (currentPath === '/mypage') {
      $zopim.livechat.button.hide();
   }
});
```

However, this does not hide the button - instead it opens the chat window on page load.

Would anyone know what I could do to simply hide the Zen Desk chat button?

(PS the currentPath works, I just haven't included the function in here to save room. I can console.log within the if statement fine.)

Comment: Try `$this`....

Comment: @SujitAgarwal it errors out with that, sorry

Comment: can you share a sample URL where you are testing this, and do you know if you are using the legacy chat widget or the new widget?  Also curious about you mentioning the hideAll() function in your question but having the .hide() function in your code.  you've tried both with the same result?  And have you tried any other methods to see if they fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hideAll() function did work, I just had to apply it to everything, eg:

```
$zopim.livechat.hideAll();
```

Not:

```
$zopim.livechat.button.hideAll();
```